# Can a subquery be grouped by a columns in the main query?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to have a subquery grouped by a field? I'm trying to get the following to work; the table is retrosheet MLB game logs, and I'm getting stats for H/HR/RBI etc. grouped by home team (this query filters by games where the Seattle Mariners are the visiting team)

The subquery values give the complete list of wins vs. losses, is there a way to get them to be grouped by home team?

```
-- mariners batting avg at away parks

SELECT 
    count(entry_id) G,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(home_team)
        FROM
            GAME_LOG_ENTRY
        WHERE
            home_team_score > visitor_team_score
                AND game_date > '2017-01-01'
                AND home_team = 'SEA') W,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(home_team)
        FROM
            GAME_LOG_ENTRY
        WHERE
            home_team_score < visitor_team_score
                AND game_date > '2017-01-01'
                AND home_team = 'SEA') L,
        
    SUM(visitor_at_bats) AB,
    SUM(visitor_hits) H,
    ROUND((SUM(visitor_hits) / SUM(visitor_at_bats)),
            3) AVG,
    SUM(visitor_home_runs) HR,
    SUM(visitor_doubles) doubles,
    SUM(visitor_triples) triples,
    SUM(visitor_rbi) rbi,
    SUM(visitor_so) SO,
    SUM(visitor_bb) BB,
    SUM(visitor_lob) LOB,
    home_team
FROM
    GAME_LOG_ENTRY
WHERE
    visit_team = 'SEA'
        AND home_league = 'AL'
        AND game_date > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY home_team, W, L
ORDER BY W desc
```

### Follow up

I am able to do a query like:

```
select game_date,
(home_team_score < visitor_team_score) 'W/L'
FROM GAME_LOG_ENTRY
```

and get the correct output
'2022-04-07 00:00:00', '1'
'2022-04-07 00:00:00', '0'

etc., but I am not able to get a count where the home score is greater than the visitor score. When I try to do that, I get the total number of games.

Comment: Nope, you cannot as correlated subqueries in the select lost can only return a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to how you're using subqueries to calculate W and L. The subqueries are not being grouped properly, which is why you're getting the total number of games instead of W and L.

```
SELECT 
home_team,
COUNT(entry_id) AS G,
SUM(CASE WHEN home_team_score > visitor_team_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W,
SUM(CASE WHEN home_team_score < visitor_team_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS L,
SUM(visitor_at_bats) AS AB,
SUM(visitor_hits) AS H,
ROUND(SUM(visitor_hits) / SUM(visitor_at_bats), 3) AS AVG,
SUM(visitor_home_runs) AS HR,
SUM(visitor_doubles) AS doubles,
SUM(visitor_triples) AS triples,
SUM(visitor_rbi) AS rbi,
SUM(visitor_so) AS SO,
SUM(visitor_bb) AS BB,
SUM(visitor_lob) AS LOB
FROM GAME_LOG_ENTRY
WHERE visit_team = 'SEA' AND home_league = 'AL' AND game_date > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY home_team
ORDER BY W DESC;
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for!!